# Deploying in Openshift a JAVA + Spring MVC + Tomcat + MongoDb project

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, tomcat, openshift

We are doing a medium size application with a couple of folks using JAVA 8, Spring MVC framework, Tomcat 8, (adding a MongoDB) and trying to deploy on Openshif. We have a web-frontend for the app as another project but in the same repository (why not?). We are looking for how to deploy both at Openshift, but deploying just the JAVA app is good enough.

The app is on Github, working well (yet without DB).

So the questions are:
Do I need to use a Tomcat Cartridge?
Which is the easiest way? And which is the "silver bullet" way? OC or web console?

Thank you all!

Comment: You can roll your own container on docker hub, and add some s2i configuration to fit your needs. I'm using Spring Boot and have dropped Tomcat for Undertow, because it consumes less memory.